# When 'B' or 'b' are typed, would not be counted with the use of continue

Tags: c

I have problem with this code.

I need to make a *program* for my lab that you *scan characters*, **count how many numbers are uppercase and how many are lowercase separately**

**When 'b' or 'B' is typed it must not be counted and to do that we need to specifically use `continue;`**

Can you help me, please?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void){
    char ch;
    int i, k, m;

    i = 0;
    k = 0;
    m = 0;
    printf("Input the %d character\n", i+1);
    ch = getche();
    while(ch != '.' && i < 15){
        if(ch == 'B')
            continue;
        if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
            k++;
        }
        if(ch == 'b')
            continue;
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            m++;    
        }
        i++;
        printf("\ninput the %d character\n", i+1);
        ch = getche();  
    }
    printf("\nUPPERCASE: %d -- LOWERCASE: %d", k, m);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was the input, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: The input was some random characters and when I give as input 'B' or 'b' the expected output must be the program to ask again to  `getche();` and the actual is the cursor stucks and the while loop does not finish.

Comment: The `continue` skips the next prompt and input. Since there was no input, the same character is tested and you get an infinite loop. I suggest restructuring the loop, so the prompt and input are at the beginning.

Comment: `if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')` should be `if ( isupper( ch ) )` and `if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')` should be `if ( islower( ch ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use `continue` you need to reverse asking and checking for the next character in your for loop.

```
while(ch != '.' && i < 15){
    i++;
    printf("\ninput the %d character\n", i);
    ch = getche();
    if(ch == 'B' || ch == 'b')
        continue;
    if(isupper(ch)) {
        k++;
    }
    if(islower(ch)) {
        m++;
    }
}
```

And you don't need the lines:

```
printf("Input the %d character\n", i+1);
ch = getche();
```

before the while loop

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer the question, because using `continue` isn't a good idea. It increases the amount of branches and can lead to spaghetti programming. It is not a good idea to practice bad habits while studying, or you'll end up using them in real programs later on.

A better idea is to use the built-in functions from ctype.h and only in case of a positive result, check for "B". Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
  char ch = 0;
  int upper = 0;
  int lower = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<15 && ch != '.'; i++)
  {
    printf("Input character %d:\n", i+1);
    ch = getchar();

    if(isupper(ch) && ch != 'B')
    {
      upper++;
    }
    else if(islower(ch) && ch != 'b')
    {
      lower++;
    }
  }

  printf("\nUPPERCASE: %d -- LOWERCASE: %d", upper, lower);
  return 0;
}
```

Improvements:

- Reduced the number of branches
- Doesn't make non-portable assumptions about underlying symbol table (EBCDIC-compatible, yay!)
- Uses `for` since the (maximum) number of iterations is known in advance.
- Intuitive variable names where it matters, instead of 1 letter names (`i` is fine since it stands for iterator).
- Got rid of non-standard antique headers and functions for MS DOS.

You may have to add code that rids stdin of the superfluous line feed `\n` characters.

Comment: I couldn't agree more but I need to complete the assignment of the lab by the book the way my professor suggest :)